# How can I give wind and turbulence effects only to the inside of the cube object?

Tags: animation, objects, cloth-simulation, collision, force-fields

There is the cube-A, which is covered with a cloth, and another cube-B is placed on the top of it.
I want the paper object to fly by wind and turbulence only inside cube-B without any effect on the cloth outside cube-B.
How can I limit the area of effect of the wind and turbulence?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can turn off wind for cloth simulation here:

[image]

result:

left: Wind:1
right: Wind:0

[image]

so what you could do is insert a driver into the wind property and set it to 1, if it is inside, else 0.

To get the "real" coordinate which is set by the cloth physics, we need a trick: we insert a helper object (sphere) which gets this object constraint:

[image]

By this, we can access the "real live" coordinate of our cloth and set the driver like this:

[image]

of course you have to adapt the if statement to your needs...!

result:

[image]

Comment: I've always seen the Field weights settings on screen, but I totally forgot about it when I actually need it! I will be able to apply this in the future when I need other settings too. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: You are welcome